# Shopware 6 override pagination.html.twig not working

Tags: twig, shopware6

I'm trying to override the `pagination.html.twig` template in my Shopware 6 storefront but it's not working.

My `pagination.html.twig` is:

```html
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/pagination.html.twig' %}
{% block component_pagination %}    
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ dump('test') }}
{% endblock %}
```

This doesn't change the show the result of dump at all. What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to check that your `APP_ENV` should be set to `dev` in `.env` file. Then you must clear the cache every time you add or change the template.

Clear the cache like:

```bash
bin/console cache:clear
```

Kindly, let me know if it works.

Comment: From the shop root folder, you can also use rm -Rf var/cache/dev* or rm -Rf var/cache/prod* to delete the cache folders. In some setups this is faster then bin/console cache:clear.